# using $addToset with java morphia aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have mongodb aggregation query and it works perfectly in shell. 
How can i rewrite this query to use with morphia ?

`org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Group.addToSet(String field)` accepts only one field name but i need to add object to the set.

Query:

```
......aggregate([
{$group: 
    {"_id":"$subjectHash",
        "authors":{$addToSet:"$fromAddress.address"},
 ---->> "messageDataSet":{$addToSet:{"sentDate":"$sentDate","messageId":"$_id"}},
        "messageCount":{$sum:1}}},
        {$sort:{....}},
        {$limit:10},
        {$skip:0}
        ])
```

Java code:

```
  AggregationPipeline aggregationPipeline = myDatastore.createAggregation(Message.class)
                    .group("subjectHash",
                            grouping("authors", addToSet("fromAddress.address")),
 --------??????------>>     grouping("messageDataSet", ???????),
                            grouping("messageCount", new Accumulator("$sum", 1))
                    ).sort(...)).limit(...).skip(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's currently not supported but if you'll file an [issue](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues) I'd be happy to include that in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, I can guess that according to source code. :(

I don't want to use spring-data or java-driver directly (for this project) so I changed my document representation.

Added `messageDataSet` object which contains `sentDate` and `messageId` (and some other nested objects) (these values become duplicated in a document which is a bad design).

Aggregation becomes : `"messageDataSet":{$addToSet:"$messageDataSet"},`

and Java code is: `grouping("messageDataSet", addToSet("messageDataSet")),`

This works with moprhia. Thanks.